# C++ whats the difference between uint64 and *uint64?

Tags: c++

Why does:

```
const char example;
```

`(uint64*)example` have a value of 140734799798420

and

`*(uint64*)example` have a value of 7004431430466964258

p.s. dont worry about the type cast, I am interested why the second `*` increases the value.

Thanks

Comment: Variable names are generally always useless by themselves. __ALWAYS__ include type information if you don't want an answer that is a guess. Remember that C++ is a strongly typed language and as such much of the knowledge is in the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you've invoked undefined behavior.  No particular behavior is guaranteed.

That said, you see different values because you are printing different locations in memory -- the first prints data from the memory location where `example` is stored, and the second prints data from the memory location stored **as the value** of `example`.

```
const char example
```

Defines a `char` variable on the stack without initializing it, so its value will be garbage; probably whatever was last stored in the location on the stack where it was allocated.

```
(uint64 *)example
```

Interprets the value of `example` as a pointer to (the address of) a `uint64`.  This prints out the value stored in `example` as if it were a pointer.

```
*(uint64 *)example
```

Dereferences that pointer.  It interprets the value of `example` as a pointer to (the address of) a uint64, then prints what is at that address as if it were a uint64.

Answer (score 8):

Your code gives undefined behaviour. Your second line illegally casts a character to a pointer to a uint64 (most likely an invalid pointer). Your third line attempts to dereference this invalid pointer.

Asking why it does what it does is pointless - it could do different things on different machines and the behaviour could change in the next version of the compiler.

Just don't do it.